# R - How do I pass the value of a variable as an argument?

Tags: r, arguments, dplyr

Noob here. I am trying to pass the value of "xmove1," "xmove2," and "xmove3" into the filter command.

```
xmove1 <- "X3"
xmove2 <- "X1"
xmove3 <- "X5"

xtemp <- filter(fullTable, xmove1 == 1, xmove2 == 2, xmove3 == 3)
```

The problem is that instead of reading the value of xmove1, it seems to be reading it as a string - "xmove1."

I have also tried to use "as.name," but the result seems to be the same.

```
xtemp <- filter(fullTable, as.name(xmove1) == 1, as.name(xmove2) == 2, as.name(xmove3) == 3)
```

Comment: could you show an example of the expected output? and what is full table?

Comment: dplyr is so fun to program with (sarcasm detection)

Comment: @DataTx The filter is supposed to be scanning for multiple permutations of a pattern in a matrix with 362880 objects and as such giving a specific example of an output would be difficult. Currently, the output is just an empty dataframe, so any answer that would populate that data frame would likely be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically supply column names, use the standard evaluation alternatives of the dplyr function (see `vignette("nse")` for more info).

You can

```
filter_(fullTable, .dots=list(
    bquote(.(as.name(xmove1)) == 1), 
    bquote(.(as.name(xmove2)) == 2), 
    bquote(.(as.name(xmove3)) == 3)))
```